# Why is my circuit powered by a 24 VAC -> 5 VDC stepdown module releasing the magic smoke?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, grounding, rs485, step-down

I have a Carrier HVAC system in which device controls are all powered by a 24 VAC pair and communicate via an RS485 differential pair.

In the past I've communicated with the bus by using USB to RS485 adaptors, but I'd like to use an ESP module with [this RS485/TTL adaptor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08XLT21S6) instead. "Easy!" I thought - just buy one [of these 24 VAC to 5 VDC step-down modules](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TLLB35X) and wire it up!

Not so fast apparently. I've been burned (literally and figuratively) in the past by my lack of understanding about floating vs common grounds and I guess that's happening again. Here's a basic diagram of what I tried:

[image: smoking circuit fun]

I measure 5 V across points P/N and can successfully power the microcontroller via PN and power the RS485 module via the ESP module's built-in 3.3 V regulator.

Connecting the RS485 differential signal lines to the RS485 module releases the magic smoke(from at least the 3.3v regulator in the esp module).

Point C (24 V common) is connected to the HVAC chassis (and to earth ground).
However, I measure 15 VAC (presumably half wave?) across C-N so it seems I can't tie the 5 V negative to chassis/earth ground?

Clearly I'm missing something fundamental, so I seek the wisdom of the exchange to guide my path. Is there an obvious problem with this circuit?

Comment: measure AC and DC voltages at P and at N relative to C

Comment: Don't buy parts from Amazon/Ebay/Aliexpress. Buy from reliable vendors that deal specifically with electronic components. "It was very cheap but doesn't work"... how is that cheap? If you want electronics junk that doesn't work, I can sell you some for cheaper than $11, pre-burnt and everything :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Clearly I'm missing something fundamental, so I seek the wisdom of the
> exchange to guide my path. Is there an obvious problem with this
> circuit?*

The AC to DC converter you linked is not an isolating type hence, because the input 24 volts AC is grounded/earthed (your diagram shows that) and, the RS485 system is likely grounded/earthed (at some other point not shown in your diagram), the internal bridge rectifier in the "module" will fry and possibly cause other parts of your circuit to fry.

Basically, anything you attach to that module must never be earthed/grounded.

<sub>You need to use a galvanically isolating AC to DC converter. It will have an isolation transformer inside. Don't buy stuff like this from Shamazon because it won't give anything other than the barest technical details.</sub>

<sub>Or, you use a 24 volt AC output from an isolating transformer and don't ground/earth either of the wires</sub>

Comment: > Basically, anything you attach to that module must never be earthed/grounded.

Thanks for your quick reply, @andy-aka. Does the above mean I could power the microcontroller with for example a ubiquitous usb phone charger brick without issue? Assuming so since up till now I've used a usb->rs485 module. But perhaps I've just gotten lucky in that regard.

Comment: You could probably do this because the phone charger (if I understand that term correctly) will produce an isolated output voltage which will be floating. However, if I were you I'd dump the crappy Shamazon stuff.

Comment: @nebulous Yes, the phone chargers are isolated. The thing about non-isolated AC/DC converters is they basically work by swapping "live" and "neutral". So half the time live is + and half the time live is -. So if you connected - to neutral somewhere else, that's a short circuit. (24V circuits are usually not labeled with the words live and neutral but you know what I mean)

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to copy the basic topology of the power circuit from one of the OEM controls. They either have an isolated converter, or use a half bridge, or do something differently enough from your topology that the 0V reference in their circuit ends up different than yours. It's also worth checking what RS-485 transceiver does Carrier use, and compare its specs to the part you're using - assuming that you got a genuine Maxim part on that no-name board.

Given the completely unknown source (Amazon bargain) for the RS-485 converter, there's a fair chance that the "MAX485" they use is not a genuine part.

I highly suggest buying an RS-485 interface board from a mainstream distributor as a starting point, and selecting one that is specified to survive such snafus.

MAX485 is not a pinnacle of robustness. Most any newer transceiver for fail-safe applications would survive exposure to 24VAC relative to its ground. MAX3440E would be a better choice here, or similar parts from other manufacturers - there's healthy competition in that space.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking there must exist a module that optically isolates the bus pair - but I haven't stumbled onto one yet. In this case the module is using an SP3485E chip not a MAX485 (though pin-compatible). While I appreciate that avoiding cheap/sketchy rs485 modules would be ideal - I don't think that's the smoke-generating problem in this case.

Could you elaborate on how a half bridge would solve this problem?

Comment: A half bridge rectifier uses one of the transformer leads - the center tap - as the common 0V node. Low power circuits can do with a quarter bridge as well - one transformer winding w/o taps. This is all not very robust since any change to polarity would bring problems. So most likely you just need to see what Carrier did. RS485 isolators won’t be optical usually - they have integrated magnetics to also power the isolated side. But no matter what, with a 60V protected device, there must be no magic smoke. I need to check in my stash for a genuine MAX485 and test it out in your circuit.

Answer (score 2):

The control xformer for the a\c unit should not have a grounded secondary lead.  The output is 12-12 not 24-0.  This is why you only have 15voc off the secondary. Grounding one lead gives an a\c potential to ground on anything downstream that is not separately isolated.  Lift the ground connection off the 24v and should be good.